# "Always Allow" location does not appear after using requestAlwaysAuthorization()

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to request location "Always" but no matter my settings I only see three options:

1. Allow While Using App
2. Allow Once
3. Don't Allow

Here is my code:

```
//  ViewController.swift

import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false

    }


}
```

My Info.plist includes strings for these three:

- Privacy - Location Always and When In Use Usage Description
- Privacy - Location When In Use Usage Description

My app Capabilities has "location updates" turned on in Background Modes.

What am I missing here?

Edit: Removed an old Info.plist key/value pair that was deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`iOS 13 Location Permissions`**

```
NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription - deprecated.
```

> This key is required if your iOS app uses APIs that access the user’s location at all times and deploys to targets earlier than iOS 11.
>
> The Always Allow option, which grants an app “background” location
>   access, has been removed from the initial location permissions prompt.
>   Instead, users can select Keep Only While Using (aka “foreground”
>   permission) or select a new option,Allow Once. So how does an app then
>   get upgraded to “background” location permission? If the user
>   continues to use the app, iOS 13 will now automatically and
>   periodically prompt to upgrade location permissions from While Using
>   to Always Allow.

Comment: Thanks. I see the problem now. Always Allow has been entirely removed and apps can only be upgraded by iOS after some period of time? Then how do so many apps I download able to request this right away?

Comment: I found out more. Always Allow is unavailable until 24 hours after you first open the app, then users will get a second request. [More info here](https://gimbal.com/ios-13-location-permissions/). I think you could edit your response to more directly explain that.